# React: Binding element 'children' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this simple code and I want to use "children" but when I use it I get this error:

```
Binding element 'children' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

How can I solve this problem?

```
const ResponsiveContainerGrid = ({ children }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid
        className={classes.root}
        container
        direction="row"
        justifyContent="center"
        alignItems="center"
      >
        {children}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ResponsiveContainerGrid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type your component like this:

```
import { FC } from "react";
const ResponsiveContainerGrid: FC = ({ children }) => { ... }
```

This way, the children prop will be typed implicitly.
`FC` stands for Functional Component, and has already a predefined `children` props. If you want to use a custom prop, then you can type it like this:

```
const ResponsiveContainerGrid: FC<{myprop: MyPropType}> = ({ children, myProp }) => { ... }
```